# Error when outputting to file name variable in shell script

Tags: unix, scripting

I wrote a very simple program to test outputting data to a file name variable.

```
#!/bin/sh
file="~/output"
echo "test" > $file
```

When I run this script, I got the following error

"./script.sh: line 3: ~/output: No such file or directory"

So how should I revise my code to get it work? Or it's not supported in shell script?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The quotes around the "~/output" are causing you grief.

e.g

```
#!/bin/sh
file=~/output
echo "test" > $file
```

works ok.

To see what's going on, try

```
$ file="~/output"
$ echo $file
```

vs

```
$ file=~/output
$ echo $file
```

and bear in mind that ~ is a shell expansion for the home directory.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the $HOME environment variable instead in a script:

```
#!/bin/sh
file="$HOME/output"
echo "test" > $file
```